# MemoryCache regex on keys

Tags: c#, .net, caching, model-view-controller, memorycache

***TLDR; I want to remove from cache all entries having their keys starting with "foo".***

Hi!

I am storing some data in MemoryCache like this:

```
MemoryCache.Default.Add("foo" + searchHash,"some results");
```

Now I need to purge these from the cache.

I know I could store a List<> under a specific key... but that means that I would have to do a lot of boxing/unboxing... the list might have hundreds of entries... I don't believe that this would be a good approach, performance-wise.

Comment: Looking at the code for `MemoryCache`, it doesn't look like it's possible to clear ranges of keys. You'd have to maintain a separate list of keys and then use `Remove()` on all of them. The downside to that is it would be potentially wasteful as some of the keys might not be there anymore as they may have expired.

Comment: Good idea. Potentially wasteful, I agree, but is this so bad? MemoryCache.Default.Remove("ThisKey Does not exist");

Comment: Looking at the code, it won't throw if they key isn't there anymore. I guess whether the wastefulness matters will depend on how many keys you have. If it was a million, then probably it would be better to refactor the cache values to let you scan (or do something else). If it's a handful, it's probably fine.

Comment: Yeah, I will go on this path, seems decent https://dotnetfiddle.net/kjRKTm. Thanks, Martin.

Comment: Ha I just found that MemoryCache.Default.ToList() returns a key-value list of everything, so I ended up doing foreach (var key in MemoryCache.Default.ToList().Where(g => g.Key.StartsWith("foo")).Select(x => x.Key))...